# Help required in building formula for validation rule

Tags: formula, validation, error-messages, junction-object

I have 3 objects Contact(standard), Volunteer job(custom) and Volunteer hour(custom). Volunteer hour is a junction between contact and Volunteer job. Contact has a custom picklist field 'status'.

my requirement: I want when a new record is inserted to volunteer hour obj, it should allow only if Contact for whom the record is getting inserted has 'Active' as status. however, if the record type of Volunteer Job for the record getting inserted is either 'orientation' or 'interview' then it shouldn't check the  contact's status(it should allow for any status).

To sum up: 'volunteer hour' should have only active contacts except when job is of type 'orientation' or 'interview'.
edited: The Rules mentioned should work only for contacts of record type 'Volunteer'

Comment: for above one you can just use lookup filter

Comment: will it work if new volunteer hour is inserted from public website
?

Comment: @Varun, You can check the below answer. It will work for your scenario....

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check this Solution of Validation rule by putting in **Volunteer Hour** Object..

It will through an error while creating the record.

Hope this might help you,

```
IF(
    (Volunteer_Job__r.RecordType.Name = 'Orientation' ||
    Volunteer_Job__r.RecordType.Name = 'Interview') &&
    Volunteer_Job__r.Contact__r.RecordType.Name = 'Volunteer',
    false,
    IF(
        ISPICKVAL(
            Volunteer_Job__r.Contact__r.Status__c, 'Active'
        ),
        false,
        true
    )
)
```

Comment: Hi Subash, are you trying to check if contact has record type 'orientation' or 'interview'? it's actually 'volunteer job' which has record type 'orientation' or 'interview'. contact has no such record type.

Comment: Then remove the contact relation. I updated my answer. check the answer now....

Comment: Thanks Subhash. Also, i have edited my question . edited: The Rules mentioned should work only for contacts of record type 'Volunteer'. can you Please modify your answer accordingly?

Comment: Check the answer now...

Comment: @Varun, Close the question if Solves your problem...

Comment: What is the wrong within answer..? Give the Explanation on what is looking wrong for you...I literally created the scenario in my dev org and checked. Please let me know where you got wrong, I will give an explanation according to question

Answer (score 0):

Validation rule syntax would be like

```
AND( 
    NOT(Volunteer_Job__r.RecordType.Name='orientation' ),
    NOT(Volunteer_Job__r.RecordType.Name='interview' ),
    NOT(ISPICVAL(Contact__r.Status,'Active')),
    Contact__r.RecordType.Name='Volunteer'
    )
```

**Edited Based upon additional Condition:**
The rules mentioned should work only for contacts of record type 'Volunteer'

Comment: Check the Question once @Mukesh, I think it won't work 100%. The Question tells that if the record type is Orientation or Interview, then it should not check for the Status.... Change the Answer Accordingly.

Comment: validation rules throw error when formula expression returns true. Requirement says do not check status when volunteer job record type is either orientation or interview. In such cases either condition 1 or condition 2 will fail and expression will return false irrespective of third condition in formula. Please correct if I am missing something from requirement.

Comment: Hi @Mukesh, Check my answer... For such cases of scenario, you can use IF Condition to get the result.. Hope this might helps you.

Comment: Hi Mukesh, Thanks. your answer is working, i am sorry but i forgot to mention one more point here. the rules mentioned should work only for contacts of record type 'Volunteer' . can you Please modify syntax accordingly? i can mark the answer approved accrodingly

Comment: @varun : I have revised my answer based on your additional requirement